# Get name of day OnChange of Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

1. Datepicker1 - format [dd/mm/yyy]
2. Datepicker2 - will show the name of the day in local.

I need to get the name of the day in the local language for the Datepicker2  when Datepicker1  is selected .
Will this possible ?

```js
var days = [
  'Minggu',
  'Senin',
  'Selasa',
  'Rabu',
  'Kamis',
  'Jumat',
  'Sabtu'
];
var selecteddate = $("#pickyDate").datepicker('getDate');
var weekday = days[selecteddate.getDay()];

$('#txt_daypk').val(weekday);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <!-- 1st textfield with datepicker -->                                            
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="tentukan tgl PK"  id="pickyDate" />  
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <!-- 2nd textfield for show result weekdays -->   
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Hari PK" name="txt_daypk" id="txt_daypk" disabled />
</div>
```

So far, i tried js or something like this :

just in case, weekdays in our native :

```
local = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu' ];
default = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday' ];
```

jquery version i attached in form :

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.min"></script>
```

Comment: did u include the datepicker plugin js ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#pickyDate").datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText){
var days = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis',     'Jumat', 'Sabtu' ];
var selecteddate = new Date (dateText).getDay ();
var weekday = days[selecteddate];
$('#txt_daypk').val(weekday); 
}
});
</script>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/zcyjq9we/

Comment: Hey thanks very much, but i cant make it work either, the 2nd textbox still blank when the first doing on change,  Fyi the form and js in diffrent location. i put the js script on below view home, where all content show in middle of body tag. i use CI

Comment: Add the script below the html within the body tag. If you're loading it before the elements are loaded it will not function. If you're loading from external js file, load file after elements are loaded.

Comment: Your php doesn't show jquery-ui being loaded, you'll need that for it to work.

Comment: *script load, not php

Comment: i already placed entire tag script  at the bottom of page body still not working, the datepicker working fine showing calendar image but after doing click on some date 2nd textbox not showing result

Answer (score 1):

Include the Jquery UI CSS and JS Library..

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'});
local = ['Minggu', 'Senin', 'Selasa', 'Rabu', 'Kamis', 'Jumat', 'Sabtu' ];
     
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker()
    .on("change", function () {    
      var today = new Date($('#datepicker1').datepicker('getDate'));      
       //alert(local[today.getDay()]);
       $('#day').val(local[today.getDay()]);
});

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
<p>Day: <input type="text" id="day" readonly></p>
```

Comment: hey, yoosuf ස්තුති, but not working , nothing happen in 2nd textbox, Fyi the form and js in diffrent location. i put the js script  on below view home, where all content show in middle of body tag. i use CI

Comment: i  tried uncomment alert, pop up not showing result.

Comment: snippet is working fine.. i think the way you placed the code in your solution would be wrong. please check again

Comment: did u include the datepicker plugin js ?

Comment: i already placed entire tag script at the bottom of page body still not working, the datepicker working fine showing calendar image but after doing click on some date 2nd textbox not showing result

Comment: can u provide me a jsfiddle  so i can check it out for you

Comment: i did, both of these file :                                                                      1.bootstrap-datepicker.js                                                                2.bootstrap-datepicker.min.js

Comment: you havent included the js file for the datepicker in the fiddle, check your code if you have included the css and the js library for the Jquery UI datepicker

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yhudhaifa/vfsr6w5d/2/ check this link,, it works, after adding the library

Comment: yes its worked, i just edited, adding external resources in my jsfiddle and placed the code that u give in the forum..but its still not working in my php page.

Comment: solution which is given is working mate, you need to figure where to place the js libraries..

Answer (score 0):

after I observed, the cause is a conflict between this line :

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="assets/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"> <===#this line

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="assets/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="assets/datepicker-plugins/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"> <===#and this line
```

seems to be a conflict between the two libraries,because :

**jquery-ui.js** may also provide ***datepicker***, so "the winner" is the last library loaded, which is ***datepicker*** of **bootstrap-datepicker.min.js**

since **bootstrap-datepicker.min.js** took over the library in used then, the event of **jquery-ui.js** does not work anymore which is (onChange/onSelect).

because the code that is given by ***Hudhaifa Yoosuf*** and ***CrashCore*** using **jquery-ui.js**, in order to function properly, **jquery-ui.js** should take over as the provider libray.

in this situation, I finally remove the line of code, **bootstrap-datepicker.min.js**. and adakadabra ..update value input from datepicker event work well..

thanks, i learned precious things with jQuery..(resolved)